# C# Bilingual Directory Separator Character for Non-English Windows

Tags: c#, directory, path-separator

I am trying to create-read/write a file into a subfolder of the users AppData\Roaming folder:

```
string fileloc = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "FolderName" + Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + "SomeFile.txt");
```

This is working brilliantly on my computer, but when I ran the program on a friend's Japanese laptop (which uses ¥ as its directory separator) they were only able to read/write to the file, and the program would crash if it needed to create the file. (I also tried the non-Alt directory separator.)

The string fileloc printed:

> C:¥Users¥UserName¥Appdata¥Roaming¥FolderName/SomeFile.txt

Comment: Thanks phoog and Naraen, so I guess there is just no reliable explicit separator then? Both are producing the desired result! :)

Although the fileloc now produces the correct location, it is still crashing when attempting to create the file from scratch... so I now have no idea what's going on there :(

Comment: could you paste the error or exception when it crashes.  Also, it is possible there is an event in the eventlog that would give you additional information about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
string fileloc = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "FolderName"), "SomeFile.txt");
```

Or, perhaps easier to comprehend:

```
string directoryPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "FolderName"); 
string fileloc = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "SomeFile.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

string fileloc = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), Path.Combine("FolderName", + "SomeFile.txt"));

should do what you are expecting.  Does that work for you?